# convert attributes into back to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, attributes

I need to first save array to  to table row  attribute then trying to convert attributes into back to array

```
var arr_Rates = new Array();
arr_Rates.push({Single:"value",Double: "value"});
$('table tr').attr("arr_Rates", arr_Rates);
```

When I am retrieving back data from attribute to array , I get attr value, but  I am not able to convert that into array and loop through values

```
var arr_Rates=$('table tr').attr("arr_Rates");

$.each(arr_Rates, function( index, value ) {
console.log(value); 
 })
```

above code gives this error:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [object Object]

I also tried

```
var array = $.map(arr_Rates, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
```

And 
`var arr = jQuery.makeArray( arr_Rates );`  and   `JSON.parse(arr_Rates )`

But still same error, please suggest me some fix.

Comment: Either use `.data` or JSON.stringify/JSON.parse

Comment: JSON.parse is not working , can you please tell me some example

Comment: I meant `$('table tr').attr("arr_Rates", JSON.stringify(arr_Rates));` and then `var arr_Rates=JSON.parse($('table tr').attr("arr_Rates"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want to store an array of objects within the element it makes far more sense to use `data()` as it saves having to serialise/deserialise your values. Try this:

```js
// set:
var ratesInput = [{
  Single: "value single",
  Double: "value double"
}];
$('table tr').data('rates', ratesInput);

// get:
var ratesOutput = $('table tr').data('rates');
ratesOutput.forEach(function(value, index) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes , i was trying to do that.but i was digging into some other direction . thanks for saving time